# 32-bit and 64-bit Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 on a singlemachine

Tags: sql-server, dll

I'm trying to import data from Excel into various SQLServer instances, which are a variety of 32- and 64-bit versions. The machines have 32- and 64-bit versions of Office, and on my own machine for instance I get:

```
The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.
```

I'm looking for solutions and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I *believe* that the key component is the `AccessDatabaseEngine` and/or associated DLLs that installs. These are available as downloads in redistributable form, so:

1) Is it possible to install both DLLs on a single machine, say in different directories?

2) If I write a program in .net to do the import, can I compile both DLLs into the app? I already know how to load the correct one depending on the bitted-ness of the host application.

3) Does an actual install have to take place? If I know the directories where the DLLs are located (assuming it's DLLs), can I simply call `regedit` at runtime to set them up, or is there more complexity?